# How can I recover trusted.gpg.d?

Tags: data-recovery

I run `sudo rm /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ -r` by mistake. How can I recover this important folder (I can no longer update)

Comment: it's just a gpg keys for all PPA's you added on your system.

Comment: yes, but i need them back (I can not even update now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem by:

```
gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key  <key_in_hexadicimal>     
gpg -a --export <key_in_hexadicimal> | sudo apt-key add -
```

Where  is simply the key that is displayed in front of any URL in `/etc/apt/sources.list`