# I accidentally deleted the folder trusted.gpg.d

Tags: apt, updates, data-recovery

I faced the error message

```
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
```

so I deleted the trusted.gpg.d folder and now I can't even update

[I tried this fix](https://askubuntu.com/q/487575/1672768) but doesn't work for me because i don't really understand what to do

and I got these messages

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

so I really don't know what to do

the main reason that happened to me when I tried to install Atom text editor

Comment: Just an aside, but Atom is an abandoned text editor. You may want to find a new code editor.

Comment: i already installed it but now i wanna retrieve my data to be able to update

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: i use 22.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

In the solution you linked to, it has text like this: `<key_in_hexadicimal>` - which you are *not* supposed to copy directly like that. You're supposed to replace that text (including the `<` and `>`) with the key from the PPA or repository that you want to re-add back to your keyring.

Comment: I just want the normal keys for the update 

I can't even update frome the softwere update tool

Comment: sadly i deleted the whole folder and its content but i recreated it as admin but i dunno if that wil fix it or not 
i tried before doing what you said but nothing